# Bind to an attached property with out knowing the ancestor type

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have an attached property that looks like this:

```
<Button Styles:ToolTip.Title="The Title"/>
```

I setup a style to access show it like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(Styles:ToolTip.Title), 
   RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"/>
```

The problem with this binding is that it can ONLY work when my property is on a Button.

I am making a custom ToolTip feature, so I want it to work on any control that would normally show a tooltip.

Normally I would just bind to TemplatedParent.  But that is the ContentPresenter.

How can I get a source pointing back to the object that has the attached property on it (and not reference it statically in code)?

[Here is my full style in case it is needed.](https://gist.github.com/4049094#file_syle.xml)

UPDATE:

This was what did it.  I changed my RegisterAttached method's last parameter to be this:

```
new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(string), 
                              FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try making the property an [inherited dependency property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753197%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Then setting the value on the parent Button would cause the child TextBlock inherit the value